# Preencher um DataGrid com dados de uma lista mas informando quais colunas quero exibir

Tags: c#

Caros colegas.

Quero preeencher um Datagrid a partir de uma lista. O detalhe é que quero selecionar as colunas a serem exibidas. Se não inibir a auto geração das colunas existe os dados normalmente. Mas se inibir a auto geração, mostra as colunas criadas + as colunas do banco, mas não exibe os dados.

Segue trecho da rotina:

```
  private void frmCFOPPesquisar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvPesquisar.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

        dgvPesquisar.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        ConfiguraDGV();

        CarregarGrid();
    }

    public void ConfiguraDGV()
    {
        dgvPesquisar.Columns.Add("cfop", "CFOP");
        dgvPesquisar.Columns.Add("Descricao", "Descrição");
        dgvPesquisar.Columns.Add("NaturezaOperacao", "Natureza de Operação");            
    }

    public void CarregarGrid()
    {
            BancoContexto contexto = new BancoContexto();

            IEnumerable<Cfop> lista = from p in contexto.Cfops select p;

            dgvPesquisar.DataSource = lista.ToList();
    }
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Tem que definir a dataproperty da coluna com o nome da propriedade do objeto que está na lista

Answer (score 1):

Defina a dataproperty da coluna:

```
dgvPesquisar.Columns["cfop"].DataPropertyName = "CFOP";
```

Comment: Perteito rovann. Deu certo. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: @GVGTEC não esqueça de marcar como resposta, obrigado